# Por qual motivo é necessário subir o ng serve em 0.0.0.0?

Tags: angular, docker

Instalei o **Angular** dentro de um container Docker ([fabiojanio/ionic](https://hub.docker.com/r/fabiojanio/ionic)), entretanto, só estou conseguindo acessar o aplicativo quando inicio o server desta forma:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Gostaria de usar só:

```
ng serve
```

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou mudar a baseUrl do protractor.conf.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não  é necessariamente em relação ao Angular, é mais relacionado a rede e docker.

Quando se usa o `127.0.0.1`, você está dizendo para o seu servidor escutar/servir ao adaptador de rede virtual que atende ao host interno, também conhecido como `loopback`.

Você precisa utilizar `0.0.0.0` para que este servidor, rodando dentro do seu container, seja acessível por todas as interfaces de rede. Incluindo às de acesso externo, no caso de servidores, por exemplo.

Quando fizer deploy da aplicação para o host, precisa considerar utilizar o `0.0.0.0` para que o "redirecionamento" enter a interface de rede publica e a interface de rede do seu container, funcione.

Se o seu desejo é deixar o `0.0.0.0` como padrão, para não precisar digitar, você precisará definir no arquivo de configurações do angular, algo assim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788609/6394559

Answer (score -1):

Usando o —-host 0.0.0.0 você está liberando acesso externo ao servidor de desenvolvimento do Angular.

Por padrāo o server sobe como host `localhost`

Oque impederia de acessar o server angular de fora do container.

Acredito que deva manter o host conforme ja tem feito.

Espero ter ajudado